# Fatal error on R studio launching

Tags: r, rstudio

I am working on a new iMac with macOS High Sierra. I have newly downloaded R (Version 3.4.2) and RStudio(Version 1.1.383). A couple of times before, my Studio sessions aborted and I got a Fatal error message. I had uninstalled and re installed both R and R Studio and it seemed to work for a couple of days and I now despite uninstalling and reinstalling I am getting the same error and R Studio fails to launch. R Gui seems to be working fine, but I am used to R studio. 
I would greatly appreciate any help!
Thanks
Poorva

Comment: Try re-installing it. As it seems like a software installation issue, you might do better to use the RStudio help forums.

Comment: Try http://community.rstudio.com/ for RStudio bugs and crashes and failures to launch.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled both R and R studio. Tried older version of R(3.3.3) and so far it seems to be working. Funnily same occurred on my MacBook as well.

Comment: Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I got this issue solved by following the below steps:-

1. Download both the files R 4.3 and Rstudio.
2. Disconnect the Internet.
3. Install both the files and now you are good to program in R.

Note: Also Make sure that the Environment variable is set.

The reason why this happens is due to some error/Performance reporting to Rstudio during your first installation.